# problem loading vue component in blade template with vite

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vite, laravel-9

I've an issue with laravel 9 and vuejs component;
I'm trying to load a component ("WelcomeMainComponent.vue") in the 'welcome.blade' but it didn't render something in the page. Previously I've loaded every component in the 'home.blade' page without errors, and when I try to load also this component in the home, it shows everything without problems.
Console didn't show any error so I can't figure the problem.
Any suggestion?

welcome.blade:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
        integrity="sha384-Zenh87qX5JnK2Jl0vWa8Ck2rdkQ2Bzep5IDxbcnCeuOxjzrPF/et3URy9Bv1WTRi" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url('css/welcome.css') }}">
    <title>Laravel</title>

    <!-- Fonts -->
    <link href="https://fonts.bunny.net/css2?family=Nunito:wght@400;600;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- import app.js -->
    @vite(['resources/sass/app.scss', 'resources/js/app.js'])


</head>

<body class="">
    <div id="app">
        @if (Route::has('login'))
            <div class="d-flex justify-content-between px-2">
                <div>logo</div>
                <div class="mt-3">
                    @auth
                        <a class="m-3 button-welcome" href="{{ url('/home') }}">Home</a>
                    @else
                        <a href="{{ route('login') }}" class="mx-3 button-welcome">sign in</a>

                        @if (Route::has('register'))
                            <a href="{{ route('register') }}" class="button-welcome">register</a>
                        @endif
                    @endauth
                </div>
            </div>
        @endif
    </div>

    <welcome-main-component/>


</body>

</html>
```

app.js:

```
import './bootstrap';
import { createApp } from 'vue';


const app = createApp({});

import RootComponent from './components/RootComponent.vue';
app.component('example-component', RootComponent);
import ProfileComponent from './components/ProfileImageComponent.vue'
app.component('profile-image-component', ProfileComponent)

import WelcomeMainComponent from './components/WelcomeMainComponent.vue';
app.component('welcome-main-component', WelcomeMainComponent);


Object.entries(import.meta.glob('./**/*.vue', { eager: true })).forEach(([path, definition]) => {
    app.component(path.split('/').pop().replace(/\.\w+$/, ''), definition.default);
});
   
app.mount('#app');
```

Answer (score 0):

I finaly solved: the problem was mounting the app in the main div. Replacing this with the body shows everything without errors.

```
 <body id="app">
        <div id="">
           ...
        </div>
   </body>
```